# Vim: Remove mapping created by vim-plugin

Tags: vim, plugins, mapping

I use the Vimwiki-Plugin a lot, but remapping `<Backspace>` and `<CR>` is just anoying. If I use `:nmap`, the mapping is shown:

```
n  <CR>              @<Plug>VimwikiFollowLink
n  <Backspace>       @<Plug>VimwikiGoBackLink
```

If I try to remove tha mapping with `:nunmap <CR>` I get an *"E31: No such mapping"* error. Is there a way to give `<CR>` and `<Backspace>` its's normal behaviour back?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

if you want to just disable it, you could give

```
:nunmap <buffer> <CR>
```

because it is a buffer-local mapping.

**or**

```
:h vimwiki_<cr>
```

you found:

```
<CR>                    Follow/create wiki link (create target wiki page if
                        needed).
                        Maps to |:VimwikiFollowLink|.
                        To remap: >
                        :nmap <Leader>wf <Plug>VimwikiFollowLink
```

if you remap that to another key, e.g. the keys in example `<leader>wf`, the `<cr>` would be reset to normal.

because in its code, vimwiki has:

```
if !hasmapto('<Plug>VimwikiFollowLink')
  nmap <silent><buffer> <CR> <Plug>VimwikiFollowLink
endif
```

same for the `<BS>`

Comment: I would suggest something like `nmap <Plug>NoVimwikiFollowLink <Plug>VimwikiFollowLink` if you want to get rid of the mapping.